# Microsoft Word protected view displays wrong formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, protected-mode

Why when opening a document in Microsoft Word's Protected view are the formattings wrong? Namely i have a text box that is out of place when viewed in protected mode.

I'm starting to think I posted this on the wrong site...

Comment: My fault, I had miss-read your question